# skip line if output already exists

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a script running on a CentOS machine that for each line of a txt file does certain operations and at the end generates an output file for each line. The script has stopped and I should run it again but add an option not to repeat the operations for the lines of the file for which the output file has already been created. How can I do this?

This is the script:

```
while IFS=READ -r file; do 
    dir1=${file: -5:1} 
    dir2=${file#*_*_}
    protein=$dir2.pdb
    pock=$file.pdb 
    output=$file.txt 
    cd $dir1 
    cd $dir2 
    /path/to/executable -ps -i $protein -gl $pock -o /path/to/$output 
    cd .. 
    cd .. 
done < /path/to/input.txt
```

Comment: Input is just a list of files on which to operate on? How do you know the output completed? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Is `while IFS=READ -r file; do`  a typo or are you actually trying to run that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, as terdon pointed out in a comment, you need a space between `IFS=` and `read` (and the `read` command should be lowercase):

```
while IFS= read -r file; do
```

Now, as for your actual question: if the goal is to skip if the output file already exists, you can just add this in the loop after you set `output` but before the `cd` commands:

```
if [ -e "/path/to/$output" ]; then
    continue    # the output file already exists, so skip re-creating it
fi
```

The `continue` command will skip the rest of this iteration of the loop, going straight on to the next line/file in the list. BTW, note that I put double-quotes around the path, because it contains a variable reference. Double-quoting your variable references is almost always a good idea.

I'd also recommend avoiding `cd` in scripts if possible; if it fails for any reason, the rest of the script will get confused and run in the wrong directories. If you can, just use explicit paths:

```
/path/to/executable -ps -i "$dir1/$dir2/$protein" -gl "$dir1/$dir2/$pock" -o "/path/to/$output"
```

If that won't work for some reason (e.g. the executable's working directory actually has to be the directory the files are in), at least just do a single `cd` command and if it fails, don't try to execute or `cd` back, because it's not going to work:

```
if ! cd "$dir1/$dir2"; then
    echo "Error changing into $dir1/$dir2; we're going to have to skip this one." >&2
    continue    # skip ahead to the next line/file
fi

/path/to/executable -ps -i "$protein" -gl "$pock" -o "/path/to/$output"

if ! cd ../..; then
    echo "Error getting back to main directory. Unable to continue" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

BTW, [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is a good tool for sanity-checking scripts, and will point out common mistakes like not double-quoting variable references and not checking for errors on `cd` commands.